# Configure multiple domains on Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010

I have configured an "Accepted Domain" for an external domain. Lets call it mydomain.com. My exchange server is sat in an internal network mydomain.local.

I can receive and send emails from @mydomain.com addresses but the recipients seem to see the email as spam. The only thing I can think it would be is that the from server and the email domain are different. In the email header exchange uses: "From: exchange.mydomain.local".

How can I set it up to send from "From: exchange.mydomain.com"? And how can this be applied to hosting more domains on the same exchange seve

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the Sender Policy Framework.  SPF uses DNS to specify which mail servers are legitimate senders of e-mail for a specific domain.  Of course to be sure, you'll need to figure out what exactly is making the recipients of your e-mail flag it as spam.

Also, you only mentioned sending e-mail and not receiving.  I suppose it could be possible that you never set up an MX record for your alternate domains.  Verify that the appropriate MX and A records exist for each domain you wish to send/receive to/from.